# Add remote: => true on Form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my _form.html.erb file, I have;

```
<%= form_for(@document) do |f| %> 
<% end %>
```

When I add

```
<%= form_for(@document), :remote => true do |f| %> 
<% end %>
```

I get an error. I want to add ajax to this form so the user can submit it, it'll appear with a notice saving "saved" and then the user can carry on writing in the textarea within the form.

The error says:

```
SyntaxError in Documents#edit

Showing /app/views/documents/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

<%= form_for(@document), :remote => true do |f| %>
```

It's saying that line 1 (above) is a syntax error.

How can I add remote true to the form_for so I can add Ajax?

#### Update

So out of the two answers, I have;

```
<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for @document, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

They both work but is one better than the other or do they end up doing the same thing?

Comment: The ONLY difference is aesthetic. Omitting the parentheses is a matter of style preference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've inserted the `:remote = true` right AFTER the parameter list. Just leave off the parenthesis.

```
<%= form_for @document, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Comment: It works! You rule! I'll accept your answer when it lets me. Also do you know anything about adding Ajax? I'm stuck.

Comment: Yes, I do. :) But to help you, ask a bit more precisely. Anyways, the internet is full of helpful tutorials: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html or http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: I've taken a look at some tutorials and videos but nothing has helped  me. Is it possible to go into a chat?

Comment: Come to ruby on rails chat room. I'll try to answer.

Comment: Ok, coming on now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

reefer this : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 0):

Also with namespace you can use

```
<%= form_for [:namespace, @document], html: { help: :block }, remote: true do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```